# Connecting to AWS EC2 failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect the EC2 I just created. But the error tells me:

> **The instance does not have a public IPv4 address.**
> To connect using the EC2 Instance Connect browser-based client, the instance must have a public IPv4 address.

[image]

Comment: Review https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html to understand why your EC2 instance doesn't have a public IPv4 address.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you disagree with the error message?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try changing subnet to a one that is public.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the ec2 instance, you can select the option for having public ip address created.

For that, you have to create it in a subnet, that has configured internet access  (usually with internet gateway)

Also, in some organizations, it is forbidden to create instances with public ip addresses, due security concerns.